# ¿Cómo saber que tecla es presionada en un <asp:textbox> de vb.net 2008?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, aspx

Cordial saludo amigos, tengo un control  en mi página aspx y necesito saber si se presiona la tecla "ENTER" mientras se escribe, he buscado en internet y eso se hace sobre un evento llamado KEYPRESS o KEYDOWN lo malo es que esos eventos no me los reconoce el visual studio 2008 , los unicos eventos que reconoce el visual studio 2008 para el texbox son DataBinding, Disposed,Init, Load, PreRender, TextChanged y UnLoad.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAgencyCode"  runat="server" MaxLength="6" Enabled="True"    Visible="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Seria bueno conocer cual es la funcionalidad a cubrir o requerimiento, es decir para que necesitas "conocer que se presiono enter", asi te podremos orientar mejor en la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Hay eventos que son del lado del cliente (directamente en el browser) y otros que tiene su "version del lado del servidor".

En controles de ASP.NET, encapsulan algunos "eventos" del cliente, pero lo que hacen es detectar una vez que se realizo el postback (la magia por detras es eso, detectar el cambio) ejemplo claro es el TextChanged

Dicho esto, es que TODOS los eventos de una pagina web se detectan y manipulan en el browser, y por consiguiente no van hacia el servidor. Para eso tienes que "tratarlos en el cliente y realizar la peticion que necesitas al servidor" (ya sea por un request ajax o directamente un postback)

Vamos al ejemplo de detectar el ENTER

- Para detectarlo hay que suscribirse (escuchar el evento) de javascript onkeypress o onkeyup (dependiendo de lo que se necesite)
  Ejemplo
  [onkeypress](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

Cuando en el cliente (en un browser) se presiona una tecla en un control lo puedes capturar suscribiendote al evento con javascript [onkeypress](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp).

Ejemplo sencillo para capturar en javascript por consola keycode (muy intrusivo)

```
   <input id="txtImporte" type="text" onkeypress="console.log(event.keyCode);">
```

Siguiendo con javascript puro te puede suscribir al evento y no estar "ensuciando" el HTML con addEventListener

```
var txtImporte = document.getElementById('txtImporte');
 txtImporte.addEventListener('keypress', miFuncionTxtImporteKeyPress);
```

Ayudados por jQuery.. seria algo asi

```
<input id="txtImporte2" type="text">
```

Y el codigo para escucgar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtImporte2').keypress(function(e) {
       if (event.which == 13 ) {
       console.log(event.which);
     }
  });
});
```

Todo esto es javascript, o ayudados con una librería (como jQuery) pero ..¿en ASP.NET como inyecto codigo javascript o como utilizo?

Aqui depende de lo que se requiera, o sea de al funcionalidad busqueda, hay varias alternativas. 
Lo que si tendras que saber es ¿Como obtengo el Id del control de ASP.NET en el cliente? Esto es para que lo puedas referencia en javascript

- Propiedade de WebControl [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)

Busca ejemplos con ClienteID y los modos que tienes de obtenerla y de que se renderice (es algo que en ASP.NET ayuda mucho como funciona esta parte)

basicamente cuando tienes un webcontrol txtImporte2 puedes recuperar el ClientID asi...

```
$('#<%=txtImporte2.ClientID%>').keypress...
```

Si bien es facil, tambien hay que ordenar un poco el codigo para que no quede todo "dentro de la misma pagina" sino ordenando en un archivo de script separado (.js)

Pero ademas de todo esto hay que "realizar alguna accion" cuando se presione alguna tecla, bueno, por eso es importante saber que se realiza con la accion y no simplemente como se obtiene el codigo de la tecla presionada.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia